# python replace placeholder values of type ( str, list, dict) inside doubly curley braces

Tags: python, python-3.x, templates, django-templates

I have a .json file that looks like this. There are various place holder values inside {{ }}. these placeholder values can be of type str, dict, or list. I am trying to replace all placeholder values with actual value. I tried doing a recursion and was able to replace key2 but for key1 and key3, I am getting issues.

test.json

```
{
"value1" : {"{{ value2 }}": "1"},
"Key1" : "{{ value1 }}",
"value2" : 128,
"Key2" : "{{ value2 }}",

"value3" : [
    "{{ value4 }}",
    "{{ value5 }}"
],
"Key3" : "{{ value3 }}",
"value4" : "random string",
"value5" : "100"
```

}

test.py:

```
import json
import re
regex = r"{{(.+?)}}"
pattern = re.compile(regex)
my_dict = {}
with open('test.json', 'r') as json_in:
    my_dict['test'] = json.load(json_in)

new_dict = {}
for key in my_dict['test']:
    new_dict[key] = my_dict['test'][key]

my_dict.update(new_dict)


def search_replace(value):
    if isinstance(value, str):
        for match in re.findall(pattern, value):
            if isinstance(my_dict[match.strip()], int):
                my_dict[match.strip()] = str(my_dict[match.strip()])
            try:
                if isinstance(my_dict[match.strip()], str):
                    value = value.replace(match, my_dict[match.strip()])
                    value = value.replace('{', "")
                    value = value.replace('}', "")
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

    return value


def dfs(my_dict, key):
    if isinstance(my_dict[key], str):
        my_dict[key] = search_replace(my_dict[key])

    elif isinstance(my_dict[key], list):
        temp_list = []
        for value in my_dict[key]:
            temp_list.append(search_replace(value))
        my_dict[key] = temp_list

    elif isinstance(my_dict[key], dict):
        for k in my_dict[key].keys():
            dfs(my_dict[key], k)


dfs(my_dict, 'test')
print(my_dict['test'])
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "key1": {
        "128": "1"
    },
    "key2": "128",
    "key3": ["random string", "100"]
}
```

Current output:

```
{ 'Key1': '{{ value1 }}',  'Key2': '128',  'Key3': '{{ value3 }}',}
```

Comment: Are you able to choose the placeholder marker, instead of using `{{` and `}}`? Or is this data given to you from somewhere else?

Comment: What should the code do for an input with a circular reference, like `{"x": "{{ y }}", "y": "{{ x }}"}`?

Comment: Thanks for your message. Its given data. I can't change that. 

Lets assume there will not be a cycle. I will create an ignore list for cycles later if applicable.